# Merge two dataframes based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes as:

df1:

```
c1  c2
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

df2:

```
c1  c2
A   11
B   12
D   14
```

I want to merge the two dataframes so the output is:

```
c1  c2  c3
A   1   11
B   2   12
C   3
D       14
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "c1", how = "outer")
```

[Read the documentation for more information.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)